# Adapter Can't Load Image from JSON on Android

Tags: java, android, json

i have some problem with my JSON code.
I want to display a list that contain text and image. The text and image stored on my online database, i using JSON for taking them down to my android app.

The JSON doesn't display any error, the text are displayed but the image are not appear.

I check the logcat and there's no error for this process. I using viewAdapter for displaying the image on the list.

Please master help me, can you gimme some simple explanation how to solve this??

Thanks...

NB. This is my code for HomeFragment.java (where i doing the JSON).

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements InternetConnectionListener, ApiHandler.ApiHandlerListener {

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private final int CATEGORY_ACTION = 1;
private CategorySelectionCallbacks mCallbacks;
private ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
private ListView categoryListView;
private String Error = null;
private InternetConnectionListener internetConnectionListener;

public HomeFragment() {

}

public static HomeFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((HomeActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    try {
        mCallbacks = (CategorySelectionCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement CategorySelectionCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    categoryListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoryListView);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (UtilMethods.isConnectedToInternet(getActivity())) {
        initCategoryList();
    } else {
        internetConnectionListener = (InternetConnectionListener) HomeFragment.this;
        showNoInternetDialog(getActivity(), internetConnectionListener,
                getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet),
                getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_text),
                getResources().getString(R.string.retry_string),
                getResources().getString(R.string.exit_string), CATEGORY_ACTION);
    }

}

public class getCategList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        /**
         * json is populating from text file. To make api call use ApiHandler class
         *
         *  <CODE>ApiHandler apiHandler = new ApiHandler(this, URL_GET_CATEGORY);</CODE> <BR>
         *  <CODE>apiHandler.doApiRequest(ApiHandler.REQUEST_GET);</CODE> <BR>
         *
         * You will get the response in onSuccessResponse(String tag, String jsonString) method
         * if successful api call has done. Do the parsing as the following.
         */
        URL hp = null;
        try {
            hp = new URL(
                    getString(R.string.liveurl) + "foodcategory.php");

            Log.d("URL", "" + hp);
            URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
            hpCon.connect();
            InputStream input = hpCon.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            String x = "";
            x = r.readLine();
            String total = "";

            while (x != null) {
                total += x;
                x = r.readLine();
            }
            Log.d("UR1L", "" + total);

            JSONArray j = new JSONArray(total);

            Log.d("URL1", "" + j.length());



            categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();

            for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                Category category = new Category();// buat variabel category
                JSONObject Obj;
                Obj = j.getJSONObject(i); //sama sperti yang lama, cman ini lebih mempersingkat karena getJSONObject cm d tulis sekali aja disini

                category.setId(Obj.getString(JF_ID));
                category.setTitle(Obj.getString(JF_TITLE));
                category.setIconUrl(Obj.getString(JF_ICON));

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Obj.getString(JF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE))) {
                    category.setImageUrl(Obj.getString(JF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE));
                }
                Log.d("URL1",""+Obj.getString(JF_TITLE));
                categoryList.add(category);
            }

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    categoryListView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), mCallbacks, categoryList));
                }
            });



        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Error = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Error = e.getMessage();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Error = e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }
}



//! function for populate category list
private void initCategoryList() {
        new getCategList().execute();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionEstablished(int code) {
    if (code == CATEGORY_ACTION) {
        initCategoryList();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUserCanceled(int code) {
    if (code == CATEGORY_ACTION) {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}

//! catch json response from here
@Override
public void onSuccessResponse(String tag, String jsonString) {
    //! do same parsing as done in initCategoryList()
}

//! detect response error here
@Override
public void onFailureResponse(String tag) {

}

//! callback interface listen by HomeActivity to detect user click on category
public static interface CategorySelectionCallbacks {
    void onCategorySelected(String catID, String title);
}
```

}

This code for categoryAdapter.java (where i put the result of JSON to the list)

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> implements View.OnClickListener {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private final ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
private Activity activity;
private HomeFragment.CategorySelectionCallbacks mCallbacks;
private String dummyUrl = "http://www.howiwork.org";
AbsListView.LayoutParams params;


public CategoryAdapter(Activity activity, HomeFragment.CategorySelectionCallbacks mCallbacks, ArrayList<Category> categoryList) {
    super(activity, R.layout.layout_category_list);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity.getApplicationContext());
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
    this.mCallbacks = mCallbacks;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder row;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_category_list, null);
        row = new ViewHolder();
        row.bannerImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.catBannerImageView);
        row.categoryImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.catImageView);
        row.categoryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.catNameTV);








    } else {
        row = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    Category category = categoryList.get(position);
    Picasso.with(activity).load(UtilMethods
            .getDrawableFromFileName(activity,category.getIconUrl()))
            .tag(category.getIconUrl())
            .into(row.categoryImage);
    row.categoryName.setText(category.getTitle());

    Picasso.with(activity)
            .load(UtilMethods.getDrawableFromFileName(activity,category.getImageUrl()))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.img_banner_placeholder)
            .tag(category.getIconUrl())
            .fit()
            .into(row.bannerImage);


    row.bannerImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    row.categoryImage.setTag(position);
    row.categoryName.setTag(position);
    row.bannerImage.setTag(position);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return categoryList.size();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
    mCallbacks.onCategorySelected(categoryList.get(position).getId(),
            categoryList.get(position).getTitle());
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView bannerImage;
    public TextView categoryName;
    public ImageView categoryImage;
}
```

}

Comment: You can post class and method UtilMethods.getDrawableFromFileName()

Comment: If the rest of the data is loading, then it's probably the way you are loading it with Picasso that has problems. Check `UtilMethods.getDrawableFromFileName()`, `category.getImageUrl()`

Comment: Is this because my image are too large sir?

Comment: Try loading that URL to your browser first. Is it loading the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(category.getIconUrl())
        .into(row.categoryImage);
```

If it worked !. You Check the  UtilMethods.getDrawableFromFileName() !!!

Comment: i can't do that sir, the android studio gimme error that said "cant resolve method .into"